# CSS is not working. Only HTML structure is displayed

Tags: html, css

I have recently started to work on web development. But got struck with a roadblock.
I am designing a page using html5 and css3.
I am using Google Chrome. And the editor I am using is Notepad++.
I completed the html5 page structuring, and added a css3 stylesheet externally.

Now the problem is, there is no change in the html page. I am not getting any styling.
Also, I checked nearly everything to rectify that issue, but can't seem to find any solution.

Then I read somewhere to check the developers tools option of the browser.

I checked the developers tools. In the sources tab, I am seeing that the .css file is not being included.

So, I think the problem is with the .css file, which is not loading.

What can I do to get rid of this situation?

Its been three days dealing with this situation with seemingly no solution.

! http://www.newstardomain.xyz/error.jpg [chrome developer tools error image]

HTML code :- 
Home.htm

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<HTML lang = "en">

    <HEAD>

            <meta charset = "utf-8" />
            <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "css/text" href = "cover.css" />
            <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0" />
            <TITLE> Home </TITLE>


    </HEAD>

    <BODY class = "body">

        <header class = "mainheader">
            <img src = "img/l1.png" />

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#"> Home </a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#"> Menu 1 </a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#"> Menu 2 </a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#"> Menu 3 </a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#"> Menu 4 </a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#"> Menu 5 </a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#"> Contact Us </a></li>
                </ul>       
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class = "maincontent">

            <div class = "content">

                <article class = "topcontent">

                    <header>
                        <h2> <a href = "#" title = "First Post"> First Post </a></h2>
                    </header>

                    <footer>
                        <p class = "post-info"> This post is written by Mohd Naved Alam </p>
                    </footer>

                    <content>
                        <p>
                            jefgvn;dfkvnadfkjevknjdlkfvmelkvjkms;dklvmdfskv <br>
                            sd;lfkvmds;lm'vdfk;lsvnrgtfiojerkovngfrbdfjovhbksjfbhdkj;fg <br>
                            ldfkjbhdfskjghepgijfkgwperogkjdfkb;sergkjfk;lbhdfilbhero <br>
                            pwrobhjpdwigorf\hwtgjpbwhreojgv pweorjbhdrjpbgtrnbgrjleiubherugt <br>
                            dlfjbptrkjnigfrbds.
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            jefgvn;dfkvnadfkjevknjdlkfvmelkvjkms;dklvmdfskv <br>
                            sd;lfkvmds;lm'vdfk;lsvnrgtfiojerkovngfrbdfjovhbksjfbhdkj;fg <br>
                            ldfkjbhdfskjghepgijfkgwperogkjdfkb;sergkjfk;lbhdfilbhero <br>
                            pwrobhjpdwigorf\hwtgjpbwhreojgv pweorjbhdrjpbgtrnbgrjleiubherugt <br>
                            dlfjbptrkjnigfrbds.
                        </p>

                    </content>

                </article>

            </div>

        </div>

        <aside class = "top-sidebar">

            <article>

                <h2> Top Sidebar </h2>
                <p>
                    dfskjbvhsdfhbvsdfvhjdfkbvodfskjbvfdkjbv <br>
                    ldsfkmnv dlfsmvn dfknlv dfkns vdnfvdfkjvnjdf
                </p>
            </article>

        </aside>

        <aside class = "middle-sidebar">

            <article>

                <h2> Middle Sidebar </h2>
                <p>
                    dfskjbvhsdfhbvsdfvhjdfkbvodfskjbvfdkjbv <br>
                    ldsfkmnv dlfsmvn dfknlv dfkns vdnfvdfkjvnjdf
                </p>
            </article>

        </aside>

        <aside class = "Bottom-sidebar">

            <article>

                <h2> Bottom Sidebar </h2>
                <p>
                    dfskjbvhsdfhbvsdfvhjdfkbvodfskjbvfdkjbv <br>
                    ldsfkmnv dlfsmvn dfknlv dfkns vdnfvdfkjvnjdf
                </p>
            </article>

        </aside>

        <footer class = "main-footer">

            <p> Copyright &copy 2017 <a href = "#" title = "eLodge"> eLodge </a></p>

        </footer>

    </BODY>

</HTML>
```

CSS code:-
cover.css

```
        BODY
{
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: Would you please post your code?

Comment: If you share some sources or online examples - this would help us a lot to search for solution

Comment: The path to your CSS file is clearly wrong.

Comment: Hey..just to confirm, have you made sure that the path to the external css file is correctly specified in your html file? bcz the main reason would be incorrect path due to which the css couldn't load. I suggest you try mentioning the relative path of your css file in your html page.

Comment: As @mayersdesign said, your path is clearly wrong. How are your project's files and folders organized? And show us the code you are using for including the stylesheet.

Comment: there is space between =   , do it like this : <link href="cover.css" />

Comment: @Melvita: I tried that too. But no change.

Comment: Post your CSS code so we can see that

Comment: @LGSon: The CSS code is right up there. It's the external CSS file. Its name is cover.css.

Comment: Is the `BODY` class all you have in your `cover.css`?....What about the `"mainheader"` etc.? ... Be aware that we can't read what is in that css file, you need to post its code in your question

Comment: @LGSon: This is all i havve coded till now. this was not working, I didn't write any code after that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help.
I solved the issue.
The issue was in the link.
I only changed text/css from css/text.
Its all working now.
Once again. Thanks a lot

Comment: Oh I didn't pay attention to the type, since I don't specify it because css is the default for styling. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the `cover.css` to the code, but as shown you added at the bottom of the html page the following css:

```
BODY
{
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-image: none;
}
```

You have to add this code to the `cover.css` file to use it as external styling or you can use embedded styling by adding this css code to a style tag in your header section:

```
<head>
    <style>
    BODY
      {
         background-color: #cccccc;
         background-image: none;
       }
    </style>
</head>
```

I recommend using external styling.

Concerning external styling, it seems you didn't provide the correct path to the `covers.css` file. A website files must all be contained in its main folder, and to refer to a file you call it by it's relative path regarding the file from which it is called. Using the home path `~` is not reached this way when loading the site on server.

1. Suppose `covers.css`is locate in the same folder of your html page, then in your html page, you call it as: `href="covers.css"`

   - home.htm
   - covers.css
2. If `covers.css`is located in a folder called `styles` that is sibling to the html page, you call it as : `href="styles/covers.css"`

   - home.htm
   - **styles**

     - covers.css
3. If `covers.css` is located in a folder called `styles`that is sibling to the parent directory of the html page, you call it as : `href="../styles/covers.css"`

   - **views**

     - home.htm
   - **styles**

     - covers.css

Comment: Since you are not new here, you should know that an answer like this is guessing, and we don't do that at SO. Always wait until the question is answerable and properly posted

Comment: @EddyG: that CSS file is actually an external CSS file by the name of cover.css .  Inpage CSS is working fine, but external is not working. Did you check the image I posted the link for ? That is the problem. The CSS file is not being loaded.

Comment: @MohdNavedAlam I added more details to the answer, check it

Comment: @EddyG: My files in the same folder on the same level, just like you mentioned in the first point of your explaination. Just like you said:  --home.htm         --cover.css

Comment: @MohdNavedAlam the screenshot you provided doesn't show any css file!

Comment: @EddyG: That's exactly the problem. The css file is not been shown in there. That's what I want to solve.

Comment: ! http://newstardomain.xyz/file_organisation.jpg  [file arrangement].  This is how my files are arranged.

Answer (score 0):

> **it's simple** first remove:- type = "css/text" in link Tag and
>   check it then see the attached example.

```css
BODY {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML lang = "en">
    <HEAD>
        <meta charset = "utf-8" />
        <link rel = "stylesheet"  href = "css/style.css" />
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0" />
        <TITLE> Home </TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY class = "body">
        <h1>Hello World.....</h1>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```